# TrueNAS shell gives ~~ at an interval and eventually causes a crash

Tags: freebsd

After an update of my TrueNAS I started getting some strange double beeps.
I thought it might be thermal warning, so I cleaned my NAS PC, put a monitor and keyboard on and booted it up.

I started to see some strange token series popping up, seemingly random:  ^[[6~^ ^[[6~^.

I thought nothing of it.

Then more beeps, system froze. I checked the monitor. It was flooded with ^[[6~^ ^[[6~^.

I then rebooted my TrueNAS and went into the shell by pressing 9.

Now I see: ~~ and the same beeps occur when the characters appear. Roughly around every 8 seconds.

What is causing these? I tried unplugging all USB devices, I even tried to google.
I found things like kbdcontrol, jons, crontab. But with my very limited Linux knowledge I could not make anything work.

Hoping someone can help me with this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General computer questions should be posted to [sf] or [su] instead.

Comment: FreeBSD is not Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong with the patching process (I guess)

How I fixed it:

In the GUI I went to System -> Boot

I reverted to the previous patch.
Rebooted the system.

Issue still occurred.

Then I went to Dashboard -> check for updates.

It then went on and installed the update (as before).

Now the issue is resolved.